# How assertion will be applied on single Testcase with multiple DataSet as I am passing four DataSet through Jasmine-Data-Provider

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have one Testcase of Login in which I am passing 4 types of test data through  Jasmine-Data-Provider. I want to apply assertion in single TC. How can I do that?

My spec file is login.ts

```
describe("Test", () => {
using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => {
    it("TC", () => {
        browser.get("url link");
        browser.element(by.id("UserID")).sendKeys(alldata.username);
        browser.element(by.id("Password")).sendKeys(alldata.password);
        browser.element(by.className("k-button")).click();
    })
})
})
```

My DataFile is data.ts

```
export const hardshipTestData =
{
  scenarios:
  {
    Wrongusername: { username: 'abc', password: 'ab' },
    Wrongpassword: { username: 'xyz', password: 'ab' },
    blankCreds: { username: '', password: '' },
    CorrectCreds: { username: 'username12', password: 'password12' }

  }, }
```

Now I want to apply assertion in such way that I can verify my testcase with all four data sets.

Example

1. if **correctCreds** is passed in TC then test should pass.
2. if I am passing **wrongusername**, then it will not allow user to log-in in that case and the test will be passed.

How can I do this??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is resolved as:

```
export const hardshipTestData =
{
  scenarios:
  {
    Wrongusername: { whichCreds : 'Wrongusername', username: 'abc', password: 'ab' , message: 'Invalid'},
    Wrongpassword: { whichCreds : 'Wrongpassword',username: 'xyz', password: 'ab', message: 'Invalid' },
    blankCreds: { whichCreds : 'blankCreds', username: '', password: '' ,message: 'required'},
    CorrectCreds: { whichCreds : 'CorrectCreds', username: 'username12', password: 'password12', message: 'Home' }

  }, }
```

Here i have written my expected result in variable "message" as well and pass "WhichCreds" to make futher condition

My TestCase.ts

```
let login = new LoginElement();

describe("Test", () => {
using(hardshipTestData.scenarios, (alldata: any, alldesc: any) => {
    it("TC", () => {
        browser.get("url link");
        browser.element(by.id("UserID")).sendKeys(alldata.username);
        browser.element(by.id("Password")).sendKeys(alldata.password);
        browser.element(by.className("k-button")).click();

 expect(login.LoginStatus(alldata.whichCreds)).toContain((alldata.message).trim());
    })
})
})
```

My LoginElement.ts file

```
public LoginStatus(whichCreds : any)
    {
        switch(whichCreds) { 
            case "Wrongusername": { 
                return (browser.element(by.id("LoginFailure"))).getText();
               break; 
            } 
            case "Wrongpassword": { 
                return (browser.element(by.id("PasswordFailure"))).getText();
               break; 
            } 
            case "blankCreds": { 
                return (browser.element(by.class("Blank_field"))).getText();
                break; 
             } 
             case "CorrectCreds": { 
               return browser.getCurrentUrl();
                break; 
             } 
            default: { 
               break; 
            } } }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would include the expected result as part of the data and then use it as to perform your assertion.

**Datafile**

```
export const hardshipTestData =
{
  scenarios:
  {
    Wrongusername: { username: 'abc', password: 'ab', loggedIn: false },
    Wrongpassword: { username: 'xyz', password: 'ab', loggedIn: false},
    blankCreds: { username: '', password: '', loggedIn: false },
    CorrectCreds: { username: 'username12', password: 'password12', loggedIn: true }

  }, }
```

Then create a function which return true is user is successfully logged in and perform an assertion on that like so.

```
it("TC", () => {
    browser.get("url link");
    browser.element(by.id("UserID")).sendKeys(alldata.username);
    browser.element(by.id("Password")).sendKeys(alldata.password);
    browser.element(by.className("k-button")).click();
    expect(isLoggedIn()).toBe(alldata.loggedIn);
})
```

Comment: My question is, If i am passing wrong creds then it will not allowed me to login which is right it means my test case is passed. Testcase will be failed in that case, if i am passing wrong creds and it is still logging me in.

Comment: What you described is how my answer works. If you expect the test not to log in the user then you set the `loggedIn` property as `false`. If you expect the user to be logged in set `loggedIn: true`. The assertion is check whatever boolean value you have provided in your datafile. You just need to implement the `isLoggedIn()` function or some other function that returns true is the user is logged in successfully or false otherwise

Comment: yes i implemented as you said and i used switchcase in isLoggedIn() as well. Now i am stuck in one more step. i want to get text from a div. which is <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="alert alert-danger" id="dvAlertFailure" role="alert"><button _ngcontent-c1="" aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button"><span _ngcontent-c1="" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><span _ngcontent-c1="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> **Invalid login attempt.**</div>. I want to get the text which is invalid login attempt but i am not able to get it. could you please help

Comment: button and span tags are under div tag which has id =dvAlertFailure. i tried element(by.id("dvAlertFailure")).getText(); but it didnt work to get the text in protractor

Comment: @Neh18 in what way did it not work? I would imagine that is should return all the child text of the element which should include "Invalid login attempt"

Comment: But I have given id so it will not pick all child i guess.

Comment: Is it returning anything?

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for letting me know